# Combined positive lookbehind and lookahead

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I want to parse an array from a custom key-value protocol. It looks like this

```
RESPONSE GAMEINFO OK
NAME: "gamelobby"
PLAYERS: "alice", "bob", "hodor"
FLAGS: 1, 2, 3
```

In Java the String looks this (it uses CRLF as linebreak):

```
RESPONSE GAMEINFO OK\\r\\nNAME: \"gamelobby\"\\r\\nPLAYERS: \"alice\", \"bob\", \"hodor\"FLAGS: 1, 2, 3\\r\\n
```

I want to capture `"alice", "bob", "hodor"` as-is. So I used this regexp, which was tested in Sublime Text and on regex101.com (keys are case insensitive)

```
(?<=(?i:PLAYERS): )([A-Za-z0-9\s\.,:;\?!\n"_-]*)(?=\r\n)
```

This is a screenshot from Sublime Text (note: I left out \r here):

[image]

When I try to capture the group, I get the next line too:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=(?i:"+key+"): )([A-Za-z0-9\\s\\.,:;\\?!\\n\"_-]*)(?=\\r\\n)");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(message);
matcher.find();
String value = new String();
try {
    value = matcher.group(); // = "\"alice\", \"bob\", \"hodor\"\\r\\nFLAGS: 1, 2, 3"
} ...
```

NOTE: `\"` or `\\\"` don't seem to make a difference.

Why is `FLAGS: 1, 2, 3` captured until `\\r\\n`, but not in the line above? Is positive lookbehind and lookahead possible? Which lookhead / lookbehind is evaluated first?

EDIT: Definition of the string array is

```
values        = string*("," WSP string)
string        = DQUOTE *(ALPHA / DIGIT / WSP / punctuation / "\n") DQUOTE
punctuation   = "." / ":" / "," / ";" / "?" / "!" / "-" / "_"
```

Comment: It works in SublimeText, since the last line doesn't have a new line, while your input in Java does. If you can assume that new line can never appear in the `PLAYERS` line, then you should remove `\s` and `\n` from your regex, and probably replace with `\h` if you are using Java 8.

Comment: I cannot assume that, my core problem that i capture the next line would remain

Comment: So you can't assume that the PLAYER field can never span 2 lines or more? It's going to be one heck of a task to parse it, then. With that assumption, you can just split the input and parse line by line.

Comment: For nicknames restrictions exist (alphanumerical), I could assume it in this example. Nevertheless the protocol allows strings which have linebreaks using `\n` and string arrays are allowed too.

Comment: Can you include the grammar of your protocol? If you ask us to derive it from just looking at your example, you are going to get half-working solution.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but can't you use a non-greedy multiplier on the bracket expression? See https://www.regex101.com/r/hN6nB5/1

Comment: @bgoldst Yes this fixes the match. Thanks! I still do not understand why the matching does not stop at `\\r\\n`.

Comment: I'm not sure if that really fixes thing: https://www.regex101.com/r/hN6nB5/3. You say that the PLAYERS line can contain new line, right?

Comment: @nhahtdh string can only be separated by `,\s`

Comment: `\s` contains new line, by the way. Please get your list of whitespaces right.

Comment: So I fixed that (totally oversaw that is included `\s` and `\n`. `(?<=(?i:PLAYERS): )([A-Za-z0-9\n \.,:;\?!"_-]*)(?=\r\n)` is correct. `\s` captured `\r\n` prior to the positive lookhead. intersting. You also don't need @bgoldst suggested non-greedy multiplier which wouldn't be a neat solution i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write the code according to your grammar. The grammar doesn't seem ambiguous to me, so if you just follow it and compose your regex piece by piece, you are going to be alright:

```
String WHITESPACE_RE = "[ ]"; // Modify this according to your grammar
String PUNCTUATION_RE = "[.:,;?!_-]";
String STRING_RE = "\"(?:[A-Za-z0-9" + WHITESPACE_RE + PUNCTUATION_RE + "\n])*\"";
String VALUES_RE = STRING_RE + "(?:," + WHITESPACE_RE + STRING_RE + ")*";
String PLAYERS_RE = "PLAYERS:" +  WHITESPACE_RE + "(" + VALUES_RE + ")(?=\r\n)";
```

Currently,`\r\n` is used to check for line separator at the end of `PLAYERS` entry. Change it to whatever specified in your specification.

### Caveat

This solution only works for parsing valid input. Parsing invalid input depends on your recovery algorithm and the line separator.

**If the line separator allows for `\n` as well as `\r\n`**, it is hard to recover from an error. For example, if there is a user named `ABC\nFLAGS: 1, 2, 3` (allowed according to grammar), but the closing double quote is missing, the list of players will be broken, and you won't be able to tell whether `FLAGS:` is part of the previous line or a different header.

```
RESPONSE GAMEINFO OK
NAME: "gamelobby"
PLAYERS: "alice", "bob", "hodor", "ABC
FLAGS: 1, 2, 3
FLAGS: 1, 2, 3
```

### Full example

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class SO28290386 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String WHITESPACE_RE = "[ ]"; // Modify this according to your grammar
        String PUNCTUATION_RE = "[.:,;?!_-]";
        String STRING_RE = "\"(?:[A-Za-z0-9" + WHITESPACE_RE + PUNCTUATION_RE + "\n])*\"";
        String VALUES_RE = STRING_RE + "(?:," + WHITESPACE_RE + STRING_RE + ")*";
        String PLAYERS_RE = "PLAYERS:" +  WHITESPACE_RE + "(" + VALUES_RE + ")(?=\r\n)";
        System.out.println(PLAYERS_RE);

        String input = "RESPONSE GAMEINFO OK\r\nNAME: \"gamelobby\"\r\nPLAYERS: \"alice\", \"bob\", \"hodor\", \"new\nline\"\r\nFLAGS: 1, 2, 3\r\n";
        System.out.println("INPUT");
        System.out.println(input);

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(PLAYERS_RE);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(0));
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you use `(?=\r\n|[\r\n])`; is there a diff.?

Comment: @joschuck: Use whatever specify in your spec. You didn't specify this part. If it is `\r\n`, then use only `\r\n`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a non-greedy multiplier on the bracket expression:

```
(?<=(?i:PLAYERS): )([A-Za-z0-9\s\.,:;\?!\n"_-]*?)(?=\r\n)
```

The reason matching does not stop at the `\r\n` when you use the greedy multipler `*` is because the bracket expression contains `\s`. The definition of `\s` (according to documentation of [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class) is `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]`, so the bracket expression is actually barreling through the CRLF line terminator and everything else in its path, until it gets to the end of the whole string.

I suppose if you were OK with explicitly preventing lone CRs from being present in the quoted-word list, then another viable solution would be to replace `\s` with an explicit `[\n\t\f ]`, but I'll leave that up to you.

The non-greedy multiplier `*?` solution works because when the regex engine hits the first CRLF to satisfy the final look-ahead assertion, it stops matching, even though the bracket expression could gobble it up.

The [test code on regex101](https://www.regex101.com/r/hN6nB5/1) fails for the case where the string contains new line since the site doesn't seem to support CRs, so we can't really do a full test there. But in the real regex in the Java code, the look-ahead assertion would require a CRLF to terminate the search, so it would end up matching the whole quoted-word list.

Comment: Your current suggestion works, but you are referring to the comment I made in the question regarding your broken regex. Keep the comment discussion to the comment, please.